# How change the background of action bar for one image

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How do I change the background of ActionBar for one image? The image I want to use is located in my drawables folder.

Comment: @09stephenb, "The OS I am using is Android" >> as the android tag quite obviously points out, no need to add that, I'll edit the question back.

Comment: @2Dee I have seen people miss this kind of thing before.